# convertion from QString to char pointer generates empty string

Tags: c++, qt

Here's some test code:

```
QString qstr_test("TEST");
const char *p = qstr_test.toStdString().c_str();
cout << p << endl;
```

Nothing is output as p is an empty string.

Here's what I got at debugging:

```
std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >::c_str 
returns:    0x003bf9d4 "TEST"   

p      :    0x003bf9d4 ""
```

It seems `p` is pointing to the right location but doesn't display the right content.

Why is `p` empty ?

Comment: are you sure that `std::string` returned by `toStdString()` is still exists in memory when you get to `cout << p << endl;` line?

Comment: @Apokal Enlightened me ! Thanks !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::string` object is temporary and is destroyed right after `c_str()` is completed. But `std::string` owns `char*` buffer returned by `c_str()` and this buffer is also destroyed. So your code is incorrect and dangerous. You need to store `std::string` as long as you use `char*` buffer:

```
std::string s = qstr_test.toStdString();
const char* p = s.c_str();
```

Also it seems pointless to create `std::string` just to convert it to `char*`. `QString` has better methods: `toLatin1`, `toLocal8bit`, and `toUtf8`. Note that returned `QByteArray` has the same issue that is a common source of mistakes. `QByteArray` also must be stored if you want to use its buffer.

```
QByteArray array = qstr_test.toUtf8();
const char* p = array.constData();
```

I think this method is better because here you specify explicitly the encoding you need to use. And `toStdString` result depends on `QTextCodec::codecForCStrings()` current value.

Comment: `toAscii` should not longer be used, it's removed in Qt 5. you should use `toLatin1`

Comment: @WoJo Nay, `toUtf8()` is superior.

Comment: toUtf8 is only superior if you want UTF-8.